# Python - Flask After logging in to my website, the session is available to everyone who visits my website

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

Forgive me for my lack of knowledge. Am a complete newbie to flask and web technology concept.

After logging in/registering on my website, the session is still active.
When I log into the admin account on the computer and launch the application on another computer/phone, I am immediately logged into the admin account.
It looks as if there was one session, it is not possible for two users to log in simultaneously on two different devices.

Below is my code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.app_context().push()
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

Bootstrap(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.session_protection = "strong"


# CONNECT TO DB
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL", "sqlite:///cafes.db")
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


# CONFIGURE TABLES

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000))

    cafes = relationship("AllCafes", back_populates="author")
    rev_cafe = relationship("Reviews", back_populates="author")


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    cafes = AllCafes.query.all()
    reviews = Reviews.query.all()
    condition = request.args.get('condition')

    return render_template("index.html", condition=condition, all_cafes=cafes, all_reviews=reviews, title="Home Page")


@app.route('/login', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = form.email.data
        password = form.password.data

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if not user:
            flash("That email does not exist, please try again.")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        if werkzeug.security.check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            login_user(user)
            session["name"] = request.form.get("name")
            return redirect(url_for("home"))
        else:
            flash("Password incorrect, try again.")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))

    return render_template("login.html", form=form, title="Login Page")


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    session["name"] = None
    return redirect(url_for('home'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I tried to set login_manager.session_protection = "strong", without results.

I want multiple users to be able to log in at the same time.

Comment: Were you able to find a fix for this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is never a good idea to modifie the `session` object by yourself if you dont know what you are really doing. Let me present you a simplified version of your app that should work with no issues.

Remember to use the `login_required` decorator to make views for logged users only. If not every user will be able to visit any endpoint freely.

```py
import werkzeug
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, url_for, request, flash
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_required, current_user, login_user
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from my_forms import LoginForm


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL", "sqlite:///cafes.db")
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

login_manager = LoginManager(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login' #This will redirect unlogged users to the login page.

# Your User Model Here

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

# Public Route
@app.route('/public')
def public():
    # Your logic ----------------------
    return render_template("public_template.html")

# PrivateRoute
@app.route('/private')
@login_required
def private():
    # Your logic ----------------------
    return render_template("public_template.html")


@app.route('/login', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('private'))
    
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = form.email.data
        password = form.password.data

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if not user:
            flash("That email does not exist, please try again.")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        if werkzeug.security.check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            login_user(user) # You only need this
            # session["name"] = request.form.get("name") This is removed. Probably updates the global session object and all users appear logged.
            return redirect(url_for("private"))
        else:
            flash("Password incorrect, try again.")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))

    return render_template("login.html", form=form, title="Login Page")
```

I strongly recommend you to read the  [Flask-Login documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately the result is the same, I can't use the website on several devices, it is not possible to log in more than one user at the same time and the connection is not secure, after logging in, everyone who enters the website is immediately logged in to the account of the person who logged in on another computer. 
I've already spent quite a bit of time trying to debug this issue, but I can't seem to find a clear answer anywhere.